# CSS webpage alignment with middle fullscreen and ratio

Tags: html, css

I would like to try to do the following for a webpage:

[image]

The goal is to have a black line splitting the fullscreen and height 80% of screen height. At the top, a small picture(p1) and at the bottom, two pictures on each side of the line.
The display would be responsive and switch when in portrait mode. I tried to made a clear schema attached.

I'm really a beginner in CSS and not sure to understand correctly viewport and if they are compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Why not? Use a responsive framework.

Comment: hmmm googled that.. found bootstrap but don't get how to install this. will check more

Comment: Also, provide a [mcve] as you are suppose to

Answer (score 0):

You can play around in Bootply, which is playground for Bootstrap. I think you're looking for something like this: http://www.bootply.com/ArGmZ2yvMH

I did not deal with the height aspect, though.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```